# UNIX for loop using awk to assign a variable

Tags: unix, awk

```
for i in `cat filename.lst|awk '{print $1}{print $2 > var1}'`
do
echo "$i and $var1"
done
```

but not working , 
i have file as

```
xyz 123
abc 456
pqr 789
```

expected output:-

```
xyz and 123
abc and 456
pqr and 789
```

Comment: Please check this link for how to ask questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you trying to get something like `awk '{print $1" and "$2}' file`?

Comment: Or use `sed` to substitute each space with the word `and` like this `sed 's/ / and /' filename.lst`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print $1, "and", $2}' file
xyz and 123
abc and 456
pqr and 789

$ sed 's/ / and /' file
xyz and 123
abc and 456
pqr and 789
```

If that's not all you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide a more truly representative example.

Comment: hi Ed
I would like to use a loop  , to read line by line, I read 1st field (xyz )while i assign 2nd field (123) to a variable(lets say var1) from this  filename.lst.  so that i can use this 2nd field inside the loop to do some other stuff.

Comment: @Roger if the "other stuff" doesn't involve creating files or processes (i.e. the stuff a shell is for) then you may be going down the wrong path, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for something like

```
while read -r i value; do
    var1=$value
    echo "$i and $var1"
done <filename.lst
```

You want to [avoid reading lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and the [useless use of `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

Awk cannot manipulate your Bash variables, and Bash has no idea what happens inside your Awk script.

If you absolutely insist on using Awk for this, you want its output to be a string you can safely `eval` from your shell.

```
eval "$(awk '{ print "var1=\047" $2 "\047;\n" \
    "echo \"" $1 " and \$var1\"" }' filename.lst)"
```

The precise definition of "safely" is probably too hard to pin down exactly. In other words, really just don't do this.